# How to call a function using a dynamic name in JS

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to call this a function following the same example that I've posted bellow. So the problem is that the method that I'm using to call the function doesn't work... I need something like that cuz I'm going to call those functions through listening events. Some one knows the right away to do it?

Thx.

```js
//variables
var ta = 3213;
var da = 44;
var s = [];

//Create string representation of function
s[1] = "function test0(){  alert(" + da + "); }";
s[0] = "function test1(){  alert(" + ta +"); }";

//"Register" the function
for(i=0; i< s.length; i++){
 eval(s[i]);
}

// calling the function
this["test"+1];
```

Comment: Wow, where to begin...  Can you describe what it is you want to do?  Do you know about function parameters?  `function test(text) { alert(text); }`  Maybe you're looking for `.bind()`?  You could just assign the functions directly to the array and call them if you wanted, but I'm not sure why you'd want to do that.

Comment: `eval` is rarely, if ever, a good idea.  What is the end goal?  There's probably a better way to achieve this.

Comment: why bother with string when you can put functions in array directly? `s[1] = function test0() {  alert(" + da + "); };`.

Comment: @brad, I can't use parameters cuz I'm calling that functions through addEventListener... and that isn't the real code... that is just a equivalent that I put here cuz I'm unable to put the real code... the goal is I have a loop and inside that loop I gonna create the functions cuz I can't use any parameter. :S

Comment: @GuilhermePassos Of course you can use parameters.  Use bind.

Comment: Sure? uhauhauh I'm a kind of noob with that... @brad

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually we should avoid eval. What you are trying to do is possible without using eval too and with a simpler code :

```
//variables
var ta = 3213;
var da = 44;
var s = [];

//Create string representation of function
s[1] = function test0(){  alert(" + da + "); };
s[0] = function test1(){  alert(" + ta +"); };

s.forEach((fun) => { this[fun.name] = fun;});

// calling the function
this["test"+1]();
```

Or simple in your code do :

```
this["test"+1]();
```

EDIT:

If you are using string and eval just because you are getting function name as string, instead you can create an object :

```
var data = {};
for(var i = 0; i<10; i++) {
  data['key'+ i] = function (i) { alert(i); }.bind(null, i);
}
```

Comment: Yeah. I know... But sometimes lets say, you get a expression string from database, you may need to use eval.

Comment: Probably, but I'd rather say that it's 1% of use cases and that people who need it will use it with a full understanding of the implications

Comment: Agreed with you completely and hence I wrote "we should avoid this".

Comment: The problem that in my real code I got that functions inside a for then their names are make dynamically too... so that's why I'm using eval. I just put a equivalent code here cuz I can't put the real one... :'(

Comment: @binariedMe Hey bud that is exactly what I need how ever I tried and my alert is calling 10 instead 2 do you know why?
`var data = {};
for(var i = 0; i<10; i++) {
  data['key'+ i] = function () { alert(i); };
  //alert(data['key'+ i] + " "+ i)
}

// calling the function
data['key'+ 2](); `

Comment: @GuilhermePassos Actually I have updated the loop. Please see the answer again.

Comment: I have passed argument with bind : function (i) { alert(i); }.bind(null, i);

Comment: @binariedMe Dude you are the best... Thank you soo much! :D

Answer (score 1):

Call it in the end with ();

```js
//variables
var ta = 3213;
var da = 44;
var s = [];

//Create string representation of function
s[1] = "function test0(){  alert(" + da + "); }";
s[0] = "function test1(){  alert(" + ta +"); }";

//"Register" the function
for(i=0; i< s.length; i++){
 eval(s[i]);
}

// calling the function
this["test"+1]();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another, perhaps cleaner, way to do this:

```
var TestClass = function() {
    this.test1 = function() {};
    this.test2 = function() {};
    this.test3 = function() {};
...
    this.testN = function() {};
}

var test = new TestClass();
```

To call the method with name 'test1' you would simply do:

```
test['test1']();
```

and so on. This works because properties of objects can be accessed through the array notation.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function using the Function object.

```
const data = "test";
const func1 = new Function("alert("+data+")");
func1(); // alert shows  "test"
```

You can add arguments

```
const data = "test";
const func1 = new Function("arg1","alert(arg1)");
func1("Test argument"); // alert shows "Test argument"
```

You can create a named list of functions

```
const myFunctionList = {};
function createFunction(name,funcBody){
    myFunctionList[name] = new Function(funcBody);
}
createFunction("test1","alert('test function');");
myFunctionList.test1();  // alert shows 'test function'
// or
myFunctionList["test1"]();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
let dynamic_func_name = 'alert';
let para_1 = 'Hello';
(new Function(`${dynamic_func_name}('${para_1}')`))()
```