# Is it possible to call a function with a variable?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to call a function depending upon the data-value value of the `<a>` that is clicked. Is this possible? I tried `[call]();` and `call();`. Both return errors.

```js
function a() {
  alert("Hi");
}

function b() {
  alert("Bye");
}

$(function() {
  $("a").click(function() {
    var call = $(this).attr('data-value');
   [call]();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-value="a">A</a>
<a data-value="b">B</a>
```

Comment: I think this questions answer will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969743/how-do-i-call-a-dynamically-named-method-in-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call a function using a dynamic name in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43726544/how-to-call-a-function-using-a-dynamic-name-in-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call it from the `window` object.

> The window object in HTML 5 references the current window and all items contained in it. Hence we can use it to run a function in a string along with parameters to the function.

```
$(function(){
    $("a").click(function() {  
        var call = $(this).attr('data-value')
        window[call]();
    }); 
});
```

You can do it by using `eval()` too. ***But note, the `eval()` method is older and it is deprecated.***

```
$(function(){
    $("a").click(function() {  
        var call = $(this).attr('data-value')
        eval(call)();
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Check the update.

Comment: why do people recommend using `eval()` if it is depricated?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function, which evaluates code represented as a string, *e.g.*:

```js
function a() {
  alert("Hi");
}

function b() {
  alert("Bye");
}

$(function() {
  $("a").click(function() {
    eval($(this).attr('data-value') + '()');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-value="a">A</a>
<a data-value="b">B</a>
```

Comment: This approach has a long list of problems and should not be used, as there are better ways of doing it.